# Why I can't find ddply for h2o in python?

Tags: python, r, h2o

[`ddply`](https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-slater/9/docs-website/h2o-py/docs/frame.html#h2o.frame.H2OFrame.ddply) is present on [H2OFrame documentation](https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-slater/9/docs-website/h2o-py/docs/frame.html#h2o.frame.H2OFrame.ddply). However I can't find it.

I have the version `3.22.0.1` which I downloaded at [here](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-xia/1/Python/h2o-3.22.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl). The in the source code of this `.whl` I can't find `ddply`. However, in the documentation page, we see a [link](https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-slater/9/docs-website/h2o-py/docs/_modules/h2o/frame.html#H2OFrame.ddply) for the source code that contains `ddply`.

I wonder if `ddply` was removed, or if it is just present for `h2o` in R, or if it is just present in the enterprise version.

Why I can't find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ddply is not available in the python api, you are linking to out-of-date documentation.

For the latest stable documentation please see this link: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/index.html (and for 3.22.0.1 see http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-xia/1/docs-website/h2o-py/docs/index.html).

Comment: Could you help me with this: Let's say I have a data frame with the meals I ate over each day of a week for the entire month. I wish I could group it per week day, and make a list of all the meals, e.g. Monday: [eggs, milk, pasta]. How could I do this in python with h2o or spark dataframe?

Comment: as a first quick attempt you could try using h2o's group_by method. please this link for a few examples of using group by in h2o python: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-munging/groupby.html.

Comment: I ended up using only spark because for me the h2o group_by seems to be very limited to those built-in operations.